# How to add aggregions for KNN search in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to use aggregations over the search result of the `knn_search` api in `elasticsearch` (because I need facet search on the user interface), but I cannot pass the `agg` parameter as in the `search` api. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Tldr;

As per the [documentation of this endpoint](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/knn-search-api.html) `GET /<index>/_knn_search`.
You just can not give the parameter `agg`.

## In 8.4

Although in [the latest version of elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/knn-search.html), you can use the `knn search` in the `standard search` queries.